# Make Google Drive files available without internet conncetion

Tags: google-drive, offline-files

I want to sync folders from Google Drive to my laptop and have them available without internet connection. 
My Google Drive app is set to 'Streaming'. (The option for 'Mirroring' is greyed out). 
The files are stored in folder 'D:\GoogleDrive'. 
I've selected multiple folders for offline storage, and Google Drive has downloaded them. 
These files don't contain Google Docs, just regular files (PDF's, images, etc).

However, when I start my laptop without internet connection, the GoogleDrive folder is empty! 
The files only appear after the Google Drive app has started, and logged in.
Obviously this won't work without internet connection, so this is completely useless.

What am I doing wrong?